# how to send post description as mail in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send mail about new post update to the user through email using django signals
but post description is not showing properly in the gmail I am using RichtextEditor to create  postContent
i am getting mail with html tags like this-"p tag" test /p tag" when i directly send mail like

```
def sendUpdateMail(sender,created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.status == 'Published':
            subject=instance.postTitle
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            email=list(NewsletterUser.objects.values('email'))
            recepients=[]
            for i in range(0,len(email)):
               recepients.append(email[i]['email'])
               msg=EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject,body=instance.postContent,
                 from_email=from_email,to=recepients)
               msg.send()
```

and then i tried EmailMultiAlternatives but its not showing {{instance.postContent|safe}} in mail

signal code with EmailMultiAlternatives:

```
def sendUpdateMail(sender,created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.status == 'Published':
            subject=instance.postTitle
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            email=list(NewsletterUser.objects.values('email'))
            recepients=[]
            for i in range(0,len(email)):
               recepients.append(email[i]['email'])
               msg=EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject,body=instance.postContent,
                 from_email=from_email,to=recepients)
               html_template=get_template("blog/postUpdateMail.html").render()
               msg.attach_alternative(html_template,"text/html")
               msg.send()
```

postUpdateMail.html

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>New post Click here</h1>
   {{instance.postImage}}
   </body>
</html>
```

with this I am getting only the text inside  tag

Answer (score 0):

wysiwyg editors display html. Use safe template filter like this

```
{{ instance.postImage|safe }}
```

or

```
{{ instance.postImage.url|safe }}
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Comment: And i forgot to pass context  in render() method